# Can Web.config transformations be used with App.config files?

Tags: .net, web-config, app-config, transformation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App.Config Transformation for 'none web projects' in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-none-web-projects-in-visual-studio-2010)

Basically, the question above.  The new config transformations that are provided for a web.config file for different environments are really nice.

However, I'd like the same functionality for app.configs that vary across testing environments.

Does anyone know of a way to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vishal Joshi has a post on this:
[Applying XDT magic to App.Config](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/05/applying-xdt-magic-to-appconfig.html)

There's also a related, though possibly dated, question on StackOverflow here:
[App.Config Transformation for Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 3):

I recently made a post about this, you can find it at:

[Visual Studio App.config XML Transformation](http://exceptionalcode.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/visual-studio-app-config-xml-transformation/)

It's based on the Vishal Joshi post but removes the requirement to change the build action of the app.config files to *Content* and also adds support for ClickOnce deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, no.

Off the record, yes. Here's the best blog post I've seen on enabling the transformations for app.config files:

[Vishal Joshi's Tangent: Applying XDT magic to App.config](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/05/applying-xdt-magic-to-appconfig.html)