# Why ought I not to install Visual Studio on my CI server?

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration, ci-server

A lot of people new to CI (Continuous Integration) install VS (Visual Studio) on their CI server "because it is required to compile the code". MSTest is a common reference brought up here.

Why should I not install VS (or generally speaking, any software not out-of-the-box) on my CI server?

(This question has not been asked before apparently, so I'm adding it for reference. If it already exists, sorry, I missed it, please merge. If no answer is provided to this question within some time I can add one myself)

Comment: @Carl - not *that* evil =) MSBuild is available in the Microsoft Windows SDK, which is available for free.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because **you don't need to**. A Visual Studio license is pretty expensive, so having one just lying around on a server where no one's using it is just a waste.There are a couple of arguments why you would still need to install a full blown Visual Studio instance on your Continuous Integration server - but here are their counter arguments:

**Reason 1: I need it to compile.**
Reality: No, you don't. You need *MSBuild* to compile, but that is [available for free](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en), in the Windows SDK. Note that there are several versions for different operative systems and .NET versions, so be careful to download the correct one.

**Reason 2: I need it to make quick fixes on the server.**
Reality: No, you don't. You *shouldn't* make quick fixes on the server - you should check out from your version control system, make the fix, build and run tests locally until it works, check in, and have the CI system do the rest for you. *That's why you have a CI system.*

**Reason 3: Without Visual Studio, I can't run MSTest no my CI server.**
Reality: Wrong. AFAIK, the MSTest runner is also part of the SDK (at least that's what it seems like on our CI server here - although I can't verify it since we don't have any tests at the moment...). However, a quick googling found [this blog post](http://ko-kr.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=80589391930) which explains how to do it without the SDK as well. I haven't read through it in detail, so I can't promise that it works, or that it's legal. You have been warned.

Feel free to add more reasons in comments, and I'll counter them.

Comment: Nice :) I'm still missing that changing the environment to something non-standard (installing VS changes some environment variables, adds DLLs, ...) leads to a different environment from the end-user, possibly causing problems (for instance, DLL on CI server but not on user's box). This needs to be elaborated a bit of course, I'm not an expert on this topic at all.

Comment: @mafutrct: Are you suggesting the fact that VS isn't installed, and thus that the environment variables aren't set and all dlls aren't present, is a good thing or a bad thing? I definitely think it's a good thing - that means your CI system will find bugs that arise because of this before your users do.

Comment: Even I totally agree that we should not install VS in our CI server, I'm giving up and doing it right now. I've spent 3 days trying to find dependencies, finding hacks about copying files from the developer machine to the server (I think this is much worse than installing VS), etc. Try to add SSDT and FXCop to the server. I'm afraid I've failed in this one

Comment: I have to agree w/@Xabs - finding all the various dependencies is just a GIANT pain. By the time I got done copying bits and pieces out of my Visual Studio installation (finding each required dependency one-failed-build at a time) - I was left scratching my head.. "how is this NOT a Visual Studio installation?"

Answer (score 8):

## You might need to install Visual Studio anyway, out of practicality

I was going to try and refute the accepted answer, posted by @TomasLycken, in the comments, but found I needed more space to talk. Even though I technically agree with what @TomasLycken has asserted, here, I'll list some of the dependencies that I found difficult to install on my CI server - and leave it to you to decide how right the accepted answer is...

**1 - 'mshtml' primary interop assembly**

You can see the problem I was getting in my build output at [this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39599358/1520850) I created and answered. Mind you, I spent *several* hours figuring out how get the desired PIA registered - and it was a result of running some .exe's on the server that came from my V.Studio installation - hmmmmmm

*CONTEXT:* I had a win forms project that used the Web Browser control.. and in the 'WebDocumentCompleted' event, I was casting the `DomDocument` to `hshtml.IHTMLDocument2` .. and that's why I had a reference to `Microsoft.mshtml` in my project.

*RESULT:* Now @TomasLycken suggests I deal with this by fixing my code. At first, I wanted to bawk at this suggestion. My code is deployed and working! But, when I do a web search, [I see that Microsoft doesn't really recommend using their mshtml PIA outside of the Visual Studio environment they developed it for](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/934368).

The offending 10 lines of code was effectively doing a little screen-scraping of data on behalf of our users who do research on technical topics in several well-known web portals. But, when I tested this code, written in 2009, it appears that the DOM it once manipulated has now changed in 2016. I know *shocking*. Probably not my smartest bit of code. Probably time to retire this function - in other words, *fix the code and recommit it*.

@TomasLyken I think is right on this one.

**2 - Win Forms Project post-build script**

*CONTEXT:* So I had come across this [cool post-build technique on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109530/1520850) that allows my app.config file in my WinForms project to undergo an XDT transform similar to the way my web projects' web.config files are transformed. Well, it just works OOTB, so-to-speak, if you copy from S.O. and into the .csproj or .vbproj source file. But, once you put all this onto a build server with no Visual Studio, the critical piece fails due to a dependency on:

```
 $(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
```

Now this is straightfoward enough to rectify.. I just copied over to the CI server my `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft` directory. *But, should I?* Since I've kinda went off the reservation of what Visual Studio *normally* would support.. one could argue that @TomasLycken's accepted answer is still right on this point, too.

**3 - Just getting all the .NET Frameworks and Multi-Targeting Packs in place**

Points 1 and 2 above, were actually the *last* things I conquered in my attempt to get my first build job to run. And my first build job is for a solution stack that I've created and maintained over the past 8 years.. so it has weathered a few frameworks and would have some non-trivial texture to it. I knew it wouldn't be easy. In fact, I hoped by making a CI server that could build *this* .sln, that it would in fact be ready to build most any *other* solution we threw at it.

When I first received my clean "Windows 2012 R2" server, it simply had a lot of things missing.. and I'm wondering if I had installed Visual Studio first, if it would have rectified some of these things straight off?

Below is my synopsis of what I had to do - but it doesn't show the pain and suffering involved figuring it all out and the false starts. Maybe it'll help someone else, though.

```
> First, uninstalled 4.6.1 framework
-- (find Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3102467) and click Uninstall.)
-- also uninstalled anything from MS labeled with C++ redistributable (a later step will restore these)

> Then, install Windows 7 SDK (installs critical "reference assemblies" and a proper baseline 4.0 framework)
-- Then, install Multi-Targeting Pack for Framework 4.0.1 (netfx_401mtpack.exe)
-- Then, install Multi-Targeting Pack for Framework 4.0.3 (netfx_403mtpack.exe)

> Then, reinstalled 4.6.1 framework for 2012 R2 (KB3102467) 

> Then, installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack (DP461-DevPack-KB3105179-ENU.exe)

> Then, installed "Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools" (BuildTools_Full.exe)

> Downloaded a copy of nuget.exe and put it in the C:\Windows directory
```

**4 - Getting rid of 'missing ruleset' warning MSB3884**

From @kevinbosman's post on [this GitHub issues thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/361)

> If you don't want to edit your Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets file, please note that it is not enough to merely copy the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\` to the build server.
>
> You also need to create the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Setup\EDev` and add the string value `StanDir` = `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\`

**5 - Getting MSTest to run correctly**

- Need dlls copied into your build machine, some must register w/GAC [more info here](http://dotdotnet.blogspot.co.il/2011/11/building-net-application-with-jenkins.html) specifically:

  - Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll
  - Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
- Need a hive out of your dev machine's registry copied into build server
- some warnings, if you want them to go away, according to [this Microsoft visual studio help forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f6f5e064-98b3-4fad-b3b5-9edeca6ce581/uitestextension-assemblies-on-ci-build-machine?forum=tfsbuild) require a *VS 2010 and feature pack 2* installation.

Comment: Installing 'Download 
Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017' from the near bottom of the [visual studio downloads page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) - this looks like a robust installer that may have lessened the pain detailed above. Wished I'd found it sooner.