# Publish web on file system with VS2010SP1 results in error _CopyBinDeployableAssemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

Cannot deploy the project to the file system.

- create new project,
- publish web, publish method, file system

  ```
  Build started: Project: MvcApplication10, Configuration: Debug Any CPU
  MvcApplication10 -> c:\temp\MvcApplication10\bin\MvcApplication10.dll
  Publish started: Project: MvcApplication10, Configuration: Debug Any CPU
  Connecting to c:\temp\deploytest...
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.OnlyFilesToRunTheApp.targets(463,11): Error MSB4057: The target "_CopyBinDeployableAssemblies" does not exist in the project.
  Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped
  Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped
  ```

Comment: It works for me. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The target "_CopyBinDeployableAssemblies" does not exist in the project.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681248/the-target-copybindeployableassemblies-does-not-exist-in-the-project)