# Do all the members of my development team have to upgrade to Studio 2010 SP1 simultaneously?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have 7 developers, plus a build machine or two, all currently running VS2010 RTM.  We want to upgrade to SP1, but we'd prefer not to have to all go at once - a simple scheduling concern.

Can we have two people working simultaneously on a single .sln with some of them on RTM and some on SP1?

Comment: The solution, project and source code file formats did not change.

Comment: Just remember you may experience things like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681248/the-target-copybindeployableassemblies-does-not-exist-in-the-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can - we have a mix of devs in the same team (working on the same projects/solutions), some with SP1, some without, and no-one has reported any issues yet.

I also don't recall seeing any warning from the usual Microsoft suspects (Scott Guthrie, Scot Hanselmann, etc) saying that you couldn't run the same solution across both versions of VS, so you should be good to upgrade at the speed you want.