# Error: The Target "GatherAllFilesToPublish" does not exist in the project, but is in v10.5 folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild-wpp

I've been going around and around on this issue.  I've got a ASP.NET MVC 3 Web application built in VS2010 SP1.  When I attempt to Publish to the local file system, I get the error

The Target "GatherAllFilesToPublish" does not exist in the project.

and it fails.  I've followed the answer described in [Why do I get the error "The target GatherAllFilesToPublish does not exist"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989051/why-do-i-get-the-error-the-target-gatherallfilestopublish-does-not-exist) but it doesn't resolve my problem.

I've installed the Azure SDK 1.8 for VS2010 (October 2012), trying to get my system back to working. With this install, I see the following files/folders in my MSBuild tree.

**Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Targets, dated 1/18/2011.**

This file does not mention the "GatherAllFilesToPublish"

After installing the Azure SDK, I've got another file/folder:

**Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.5\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Targets, dated 9/27/2012.**

This file does contain the "GatherAllFilesToPublish" target.

Apparently my Publish function in VS2010 isn't using the v10.5 folder's targets.  Does anyone have any suggestions to resolve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989051/why-do-i-get-the-error-the-target-gatherallfilestopublish-does-not-exist

Comment: @roadsunknown, Yeah, I referenced that question in my original question.  My situation didn't match that scenario.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the answer is...

At some point in the past, the project had been edited to include a local copy of the msbuild folder and I had forgotten about it.  I used sysinternals' procmon to find the file access and it was only referencing msbuild under my project.

With that, i renamed the folder, edited the csproj file to remove the localized references for the MSBuildExtensionsPath32, and reloaded the project.

I was able to successfully publish my app.

Comment: Ran into this problem and it was because I had some leftover thing referencing Visual Studio 10.0 while I had it loaded in Visual Studio 12.0 (aka Visual Studio 2013). Unloaded my project, right clicked/edited project file, found it, switched 10.0 to 12.0, reloaded it, and then it published.