# VB Error : Could not load file or assembly or one of it's dependencies

Tags: vb.net, oracle, visual-studio

I have project VB.Net. Project had successfully started
 on Visual Studio 2010. But when it started on Visual Studio 2017, it appeared errors as below.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\reflection\assembly.cs:line 1515
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.get_ExportedTypes() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\reflection\assembly.cs:line 767
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.VisualTreeService.GetEnumTypes()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.VisualTreeService.HandleEnumsRequest(EmptyRequestInfo request)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.Networking.ProtocolHandler.HandleMessage[TMessage,TReply](Func`2 callback, Message request)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.Networking.ProtocolHandler.c__DisplayClass25_0`2.b__0(Message message)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.Networking.ProtocolHandler.OnMessageReceived(Byte[] buffer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.Networking.ProtocolHandler.ReadThread()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\thread.cs:line 68
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 954
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 901
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 890
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\thread.cs:line 105
```

Please help me to solve this. Thank You!

Comment: Did you update your dll without updating your reference in project properties?

Comment: Check the compile options. Did you select 32-bit instead of 64-bit (or vice versa)?

Comment: Why did you tag "vb6-migration"? Neither VS 2010 nor 2017 supports VB6.

Comment: Is it on one machine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779518/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: There could be several reasons for this error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly "Oracle.DataAccess" or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779518/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-or-one-of-its-dependencies)