# "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess'" Error in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle12c

I just installed VS 2019 and trying to run a .Net app from within VS 2019 and keep getting "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

The same application runs just fine in VS 2017 and I can't seem to pinpoint the issue.
I checked project and build properties in both VS 2017 and 2019 and they are identical. I tried to register Oracle data access DLL to make sure they show up in GAC, even though the reference to DLL is set to "bin" folder of the project, all to no avail.

Shouldn't it use the DLL set in its reference (DLL in bin folder)? Is it possible it is ignoring it and trying to use what is in GAC?

Any hints as what to try next is appreciated.

This is what I see when checking different versions.

I have both 32 and 64 bits installed.

```
E:\oracle\product\12.2.0\client_64>gacutil /l|findstr Oracle.DataAccess
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
```

Comment: Have you tried the various things suggested here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779518/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: Yes, I re-registered both 32 and 64 bit clients using OraProvCfg.exe /action:gac /providerpath:E:\oracle\product\12.2.0\client_64\ODP.NET\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll and OraProvCfg.exe /action:gac /providerpath:E:\oracle\product\12.2.0\client_32\ODP.NET\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Comment: I tried re-registering using GACUTIL, same problem still

Comment: @NoBullMan, 
I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all my projects worked in VS 2017 and stopped working in VS 2019, I thought this probably has nothing to do with Oracle Data Access version otherwise it would not  have worked in VS 2017 either.

The solution was to enable 64-bit version of IIS express. Once I did that all was well.

In Visual Studio, go to:

```
Tools
Options
Project and Solutions
Web Projects
Check the option: “Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects”
```