# Specified condition "$(CleanWPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)" evaluates to "" instead of a boolean.

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, webdeploy

At first my only problem was that while trying to publish I clicked on `Start Preview` and got this error:

```
Specified condition "$(CleanWPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)" evaluates to "" instead of a boolean.
```

then searching for solution on the internet made my problem worse to the point that I can not load the project any more with the same error.

```
C:\Users\Syed Farjad Zia Zaid\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\SageInventrica\SageInventrica\SageInventrica.csproj : error  : Specified condition "$(CleanWPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)" evaluates to "" instead of a boolean.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
```

Naturally I tried to search for a solution and tried all possible combinations of deleting `.user`, `.suo`, closing and opening Visual Studio etc but nothing helped me except for deleting this File:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
```

But then I can not publish a zip getting the error:

```
The target "Package" does not exist in the project.
```

and when I try to publish to Server Directly I get the error:

```
The target "MSDeployPublish" does not exist in the project.
```

I have been trying to find the solution for this for about 2 days now. May be I am not looking at the right places but I really need help to fix this...

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this method:
http://irisclasson.com/2013/10/02/visual-studio-error-cleanwppallfilesinsinglefolder-evaluates-to-instead-of-a-boolean/

Comment: For the second problem , have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681248/the-target-copybindeployableassemblies-does-not-exist-in-the-project

Comment: @DeJaVo yes I have tried this and I am still getting the error...

Comment: @DeJaVo the link didnt work for me... I also tried reinstalling visual studio...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this problem by restarting Visual Studio as Admin, and publishing again,  **but making sure NOT to preview the publish actions.**