# VS Setup Project target app.config in ..obj\x86\Release

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, app-config, setup-project, slowcheetah

I created an `app.config` transform for my WinForms project using Dan Abramov's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud). Works great and the config file is transformed and present in the correct obj folder.

When I look at the outputs for the Primary Output of my application, it gets the `app.config` from the project directory instead of the corresponding obj folder like everything else...a big oversight, in my opinion, by MSFT. Obviously, they didn't have transforms in mind for all config file types.

So now, how do I get the Primary Output of my main project to output the config file from the obj folder based on the build configuration?

Comment: Why not use the files directly instead of a project output? This way you can control the source.

Comment: @Cosmin I could, but I am trying to automate my build process and that would require me to select a file based on the build configuration. I am using the config transform to change WCF URLs, which change based on my build.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the work around I was looking for [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1596387/4050004.aspx). Scroll to the bottom and see kakoskin's answer. In conjunction with [Dan Abramov's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud), I was able to get the results I was looking for. Here's the MSBuild code I used:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="exists('app.$(Configuration).config')">
<TransformXml Source="app.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="app.$(Configuration).config" />
<!-- Force build process to use the transformed configuration file from now on. -->
<ItemGroup>
  <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="app.config" />
  <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
    <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
  </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
<TransformXml Source="App.config" Transform="app.$(Configuration).config" Destination="App.Transformed.config" />
```

The `<ItemGroup>` section will remove the app.config file from the corresponding obj\ folder and replace it with the transformed config file, which is not needed but I left it in there anyways.

Hope this helps others out as well!

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I still get the un-transformed config in the MSI generated by the Setup Project

Comment: @fuzzbone: did you put the code in the project file for the Setup Project or the project file of the project that contains the config file you are looking to transform?

Comment: I put the code in the csproj - the project file that contains the config file I tried to transform.  No luck.  I've given up on Setup Projects and am learning WIX...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) (a VS extension) which enables you to transform app.config in the same way that web.config works. Also your scenario for transforming app.config for a setup project is supported.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll have to check this out with the next project I do. I did get an app.config to transform as stated previously, but it was definitely a pain. Why the VS team didn't think/care that anyone would want to transform an app.config is beyond me. Thanks again for the response!