# Configuration settings only for development

Tags: .net, application-settings, slowcheetah, configsource

**Short**
I want to set certain applicationSetting values to specific values only for my development machine in a config file that cannot be checked in. For this I was thinking to use the configSource attribute with a user.config file. This attribute, however throws an exception when the file is not present.

**Extended**
I have a library with the following app.config file:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <A.NameSpace.Settings>
        <setting name="ASettingName" serializeAs="String">
            <value>aSettingValue</value>
        </setting>
    </A.NameSpace.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Another library is going to use this library and has two options and one described a bit further

- Not fill in the A.NameSpace.Settings node so the default `aSettingValue` is used
- Fill in the A.NameSpace.Settings node so the newly configured value is used

This is handy because our build script that prepares setups can now replace environment-dependant parameters (eg: servernames, ports etc)

Now a third option is to have a app.config like this:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <A.NameSpace.Settings configSource="user.config" />         
</applicationSettings>
```

and define the same value in a `user.config` file that is not checked in. This is awesome.
Except that in not-dev environment this user.config file should not present and an exception will be thrown when the file is not found.

How can I define configuration values only for my dev machine?

Comment: why not use config transforms:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) is what you are looking for.

Scott Hanselman blogged about it:
[SlowCheetah - Web.config Transformation Syntax now generalized for any XML configuration file](http://goo.gl/MPpBn)

Comment: RIGHT! I read that some time ago and totally forgot about it!

Comment: Yes SlowCheetah is what u r looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could use config transforms. I will find some documentation on how to accomplish this and post it shortly.

Here is the [hanselman article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx) real quick that may help.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using ant/maven or something like this