# Can I change between two connection strings easily with LINQ to SQL DataContexts?

Tags: linq-to-sql, connection-string

I'm confused on how to do what the title says.

Basically I have two connection strings in my config file, a production one, and a development one.

I have a simple class library project that is basically my data access layer, that I want to unit test.  I don't want to run all the unit tests on my production database so I would like it to use a different connection string.

On startup and teardown of my tests project it will create the necessary tables and temporary data in my development database, while with my real project I would like it to use the production one.

In my Data Access layer class library do I just expose the DataContext or some method to switch modes (debug, production)?  Then the only way I can think to change the connection string is through the DataContext.Connection.ConnectionString property...but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Any insight would on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new instance of the datacontext, you can pass along the connection string you intend to use with it:

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext(connectionString);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a web based solution you can use [web.config transformation](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=config%20file%20transformation%20visual%20studio&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-gb:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&redir_esc=&ei=u69jT6z_G8Xa8QO6wqGPCA) to obtain different .config files for debug and production.

If you are creating a desktop solution then it's more difficult but there are work arounds available.  See this SO article: [App.Config Transformation for projects which are not Web Projects in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud)