# App.config transformation for appharbor background workers

Tags: c#, app-config, appharbor

I would like to use app.config transformation as it is done for web.config on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) background workers. I tried the solution proposed in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109530/125804) but it doesn't seem to work. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppHarbor actually already applies transforms before backgroundworkers are deployed, but the problem is that the file names no longer match up. So if we're transforming App.config, we look for a transformation called App.Release.config. After the build however, the file name will generally be ExecutableName.exe.config and there's no matching transform for that.

We're thinking of ways to work around this problem. In the mean time, you can rename your transformation to match the runtime configuration file name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) (a VS extension) to transform app.config in the same way that web.config. Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: thank you for the link. My problem is that I don't build my app locally using vstudio. My app is built just before deployment, in the cloud, using msbuild. I don't have much control on the build process.