# Deploy asp.net app for several instances on a server and adapt config file

Tags: asp.net, .net, deployment, web-config

Our project represents a web application on ASP.NET MVC base. It has a lot of configurations in its web.config file: log file location, DB connection string, file storage folders etc.

In general the automatic deployment of such an application is not a big deal. In our case though we have several instances of that application on the same server. So when deploying we have to make a lot of changes in the config file of each instance (adapt DB connection string, file storage folders and all the stuff).

Currently we're using a custom deployment tool, but it's too buggy and I can't rely on it. So I'm searching for a better tool or combination of tool that can be used in our scenarion.

In general it should allow:
 * automatic deployment to all the instances on the server
 * specific manipulation on the config file of every single instance (e.g. XPath, XML Element replacement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using the [transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) capability built into visual studio and [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx). This allows you to specify different transforms for your config files, producing output configs for use in different environments/folders.

You can set this up for app or web.configs. I'm guessing it can be done on any xml file really.

You should also be able to work with [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) to perform whatever tasks you need beyond the transforms.

MSBuild has many [tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx) already written for common scenarios.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109530/444610) to the following SO question for using the transform functionality for app.configs: [App.Config Transformation for projects which are not Web Projects in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud)