# Web.Config transformations - File Names

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

I am familiar with Web.Config transformations where the transformation for each configuration is in the following format Web.{configurationName}.config.

I have now inherited a solution where the transform for each Web.Config follows the following format Web.{configurationName}.Transform.config.  The transform files are shown as linked/sub files to Web.config, but visual studio does not recognize them as transformation files thus does not apply the transformations.

Is there perhaps a VS add-inn that has been used to create these that I am not aware of?

Comment: Possibly! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they used the VS plugin "SlowCheetah - XML Transforms" that can be found here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Scott Hanselman has a great article about it : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

You may take a look and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: SlowCheetah won't add files in that naming pattern.