# Webservice applicationSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a C# library which needs to reference 2 Web Services, one when the site is in "Stage" and then point to another when in "Production". How can I set up different URLs for the web service? I noticed that the URL is hard coded in the .disco file. Is there way to do this dynamical set this? I also tried this solution:

[App.Config Transformation for projects which are not Web Projects in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud)

But for some reason when I compile my web site, the library is compiled but the app config does not get copied to the bin folder. So I am assuming my Web Service URLS are hard coded in the library dll. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What .net framework does your c# library use?

Comment: Can you add this to the web or app.config file , settings or write code that determines which domain you are running on and based on the Domain read that value from the config file.. ? how are you currently consuming both the web services you can have multiple in the same project.. do you have an App_WebReferences folder..? this is where you can add / consume multiple Web Services and if you do it thru the IDE it will know the Difference I would right click on the app_WebReferences folder and Name the web service differently and then add it should be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a little bit more info may be needed, but here's what I can tell you early on:

you can always set your server (host) to "offer" two different endpoints for the same exact service, that is configurable from visual studio with your WCF configuration option.

If you mean to "point" to different urls that have the same web service definition, then you just need to instantiate the proxy that you created when adding the web reference, and in the constructor you provide the other url you are using in production.

Your web config usually is copied to your bin folder, maybe you should check your deployment installation process. or try to add it yourself.

Comment: Thx - I had to change the constructor to use the web config -

Answer (score 1):

You said that you compile your "website", suggesting you have a website project which is referencing the class library project where your webservice references are.

If yes, the website will have a web.config file - do the transformations on that, not an app.config in the class library project.