# Seeing XML Transforms happen after building a project

Tags: xml, visual-studio, msbuild, build-process, slowcheetah

I'm using [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) to transform my `App.config` file for debug and release purposes. When I right click `App.Debug.Config` and click `Preview Transform` I see the correct results. Also when I build the project with the relevant config and go to the `obj` directory I see the correct result.

Is there any way I can make the `App.config` itself file actually change according to which build config I have selected when I build the project in Visual Studio?

Comment: are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud

Comment: No, that was the link that lead me to using SlowCheetah :) I just want to see the config files transform as I'm building the project in Visual Studio, not only after a publish or whatever