# c# programmatically add service reference

Tags: c#, service

I created a visual studio 2012 C# class library, that uses a several service references. I have a development endpoint and test endpoint(i.e dev.addtwonumbers?WSDL and test.addtwonumber?WSDL). I was wondering if there was a easy way in VS2012 to change the endpoints, without going to each of the service reference.

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint actually used at run time is controlled in your config file (usually App.config or Web.config, depending on what sort of project you're in). You can use [Web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) or an equivalent for other config files (e.g. [SlowCheetah](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx) or [a more manual approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109530/781792)) to swap between your different endpoint configurations easily.