# EF6 connection strings for test/production versions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, deployment, ado.net

I'm sure this sounds familiar: An application is in production and connects to a live database. Meanwhile, the next version of that application is used by developers (their own executables and a development database) and testers (test executables and a test database).

In EF6, the connection string is either specified in app.config or passed in as a parameter to the DBContext constructor. Whenever a test version is released, I need to **manually** replace that app.config (or the connection string) with the test version and the same needs to happen when we implement.

It seems there must be a better (automated and less risky) way of doing this, but I have not figured out what that would be. Am I missing something elegant and built-in, or is there a best practice that I should know about?

Comment: You can use XSLT transformations, or SlowCheetah. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud

Comment: That seems to be the way to go! Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XSLT transformations, or SlowCheetah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud). Personally I've only used XSLT transformations, and the only thing was that the app.config needs to be writeable which didn't work nice with TFS in commandline local builds.