# Connect to a different connection string on release

Tags: deployment, connection-string

I have 2 databases created with the exact same schema, one is made for dev and the other will be used for prod. How can I connect to the prod database when the application is released or when running in release mode. Right now I'm connected to a database through Entity Framework which uses the connection string to the dev database.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Comment: Yes it's a desktop app @PrestonGuillot

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: SlowCheetah is just an addin to run Web.config transformation locally, isn't it? You have to run normal transformation when publish your app on prod.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App.Config Transformation for projects which are not Web Projects in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud)

Comment: @abatishchev SlowCheetah can be run on build servers in the same way it's run locally - the Visual Studio plugin just deals with the wiring so it's automagic when you F5. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string to the database is usually set in a configuration file. In your project, you have an app.config file that is copied to the output directory and renamed to match your application exe name, e.g. MyApplication.exe.config.

Basically, you have to change the connection string in this file after the deployment to your production environment. Later, if you don't have any changes to your config file in a new release, you don't need to overwrite it when you deploy the new release.

If you don't deploy your project very often or with a large number of different connection strings, you can carry out this step manually. If you want to automate this step, have a look at this [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx) (as @abatishchev also wrote in the comments). However, keep in mind that the connection string contains sensitive information that might need to be encrypted. As you might deploy your application to several systems, it might not be possible to store an encrypted value in your rev environment that is valid on all target systems.

Answer (score 0):

To me this is a deployment question. You can use something like web deploy http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx which is part of visual studio or tools such as Micorosoft's release management http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/release-management-vs.aspx or OctopusDeploy http://octopusdeploy.com/).

You can use these deployment tools to ensure that a specific version of your configuration file gets deployed to each environment. So if I was deploying to test it would deploy the test configuration. For live release it would know to deploy the release config.

You can also use powershell and other scripting tools to create scripts that will modify your config files as part of the build and release process.