# Dynamic connection strings based on Production/Debug flag

Tags: c#, connection-string

I am writing a C# .NET 4.5-based Windows Forms application.

I'd like to set a flag (Boolean) in one of the classes (probably the main Form's class) that defines whether the app is running in Production of Debug mode.  I will use this flag to control various actions of the app, including GUI-based actions as well as which connection string to use.

I don't have a problem with the GUI-based stuff because the flag is defined in the main Form's class, but I'm having a problem with the connection string.  There is a separate class for DB access, which basically just defines a constant like this:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class DatabaseInterface
    {
        public static string MyConnectionString = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db";
    }
}
```

I'd like to change the connection string (really just the "server") depending on that production/debug flag.  I do NOT want to put an if/then/else in every place where the connection string is used (to toggle between debug and production strings), but would like a single named connection string that can be used throughout the app.  I'd also prefer to NOT have to instantiate a `DatabaseInterface` object (I know I could dynamically change this in the "get" definition of a public property of the `DatabaseInterface` class).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Rather than tackle this in code, you should look at using the config file. If you're using a web application you can use web config transforms to specify what your debug and release configs look like (see this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx).  If not you can create a debug and release version of your app.config and use the build events to choose which one you want to use by copying the correct one to app.config.

Comment: Have a look here regarding app.config and transformations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud

Comment: We can't use an app.config due to not wanting to expose the connection string to users.  App.configs are generally plain text, and the methods for encrypting them didn't seem feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this based on a flag and don't want the if everywhere, I'd suggest that you use a simple getter like this :

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class DatabaseInterface
    {
        public static string getConnectionString()
        {
            return myFlag ? "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db" : "AnotherString";
        }
    }  
 }
```