# Is it possible to define a variable in the config?

Tags: c#, variables, path, console, config

Hey all quick question from someone new to C#/programming. I have a console app where one of my string variables in the job is a path to a directory. However, I am always changing it between 2 different paths (1 prod and 1 dev). So I constantly need to recompile/rebuild the solution when I want to change the hard-coded path.

Is there a way to define it somehow in the config and then a variable in the job can point to it somehow? I'd like to just get away from having the path hard-coded in the solution.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are looking for application settings. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

That is what settings are for. Easiest way to add them is via the project properties:

[image]
After you added them you will get a grid to enter a default value.
This value can be accessed in code via:

```
var path = MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.PATH;
```

The default value is stored in the `app.config` file, which is right next to the `MyApp.exe` as `MyApp.exe.config`. If you choose the setting to be "user-changeable" a changed value (after calling `MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`) is stored in `%AppData%`.

See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud) question on how to transform the `app.config` depending on build-type.

Comment: Thanks! I now see the following in my config. So I can just constantly change the string value in the config on the fly? 

 <applicationSettings>
        <StackLogCheck.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="directoryPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>@"\\PathtothedirectoryIwant*****\"</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Setting1" serializeAs="String">

Comment: Yes, you can do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an `app.config` file to your project by right-clicking it in Solution Explorer. app.config is XML file.
2. In app.config, under  section, add your path like this:
   [image]
3. Access `path` in code like this:

   string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"];
4. Then just change the value inside app.config when you want to point to a different path, without recompiling your code.

Comment: This is about the same as what my suggestion does "behind the covers", but is not as easy to use and error-prone (e.g. no compile-time check if the key exists) => NOT the best recommendation for beginners like the OP stated he is IMHO...

Comment: There are pros and cons. This is an alternative to your good solution. This is self-contained and introduces a new C# developer to how the settings actually work :)

Comment: You are right with `introduces a new C# developer to how the settings actually work` and because of this it is also a good answer here, but I see no "pros" in this case, only cons (no compile-time check, hard-coded "key"-string, ...) - what "pro" am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to chrfin's answer is to define the variable as so

```
#if Debug
   string myPath = "something";
#else
   string myPath = "something else";
```

then when you choose your build type it will change the line of code that is compiled.

Comment: I agree @chrfin, but it seems strange to include a development variable into the app.config

Comment: This would still need recompiling. And that is explicitly not wanted by the author.

Comment: @Edin - The OP would be creating a debug and release version anyway I would believe so it shouldn't need to be constantly changed in code

Comment: Yes, but you are not able to switch the path in the compiled version, be it Debug or else. You need at least two compilations. On the other hand, what if I want to test a Release version with the Dev-Server? I might want to do that, for all kind of reasons, performance tests, behavior tests etc... You are bundling build configuration to the environment which is not a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think any folder paths should ever be hard coded but that isn't the question here. @edin - I explicitly state this is an alternative to chrfin's answer as it is something that the OP may not be aware of

Comment: I see, but offering it as an answer could be a bit misleading :)