# Handle config transforms for app.config in Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to handle the config transform for app.config in Visual studio 2013 without any 3rd party tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App.Config Transformation for projects which are not Web Projects in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This previous post has all the info you need - how to do it with a plugin (slow cheetah) then how to do it 'manually' further down
[App.Config Transformation for projects which are not Web Projects in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud)