# Multiple appConfigs wrapping up into one

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I am working on a project that has 11 different projects in one solution. 
In here are a main website and many console supporting apps. The web site and the console apps each have their own appConfigs. So far there is not a central location for code so it has been duplicated in a couple different projects. I am currently attempting to rip out the duplicated code and throw it into a new project which all the apps and web site will consume. We have two different web sites and three different console apps each which build their own config.

So my question is what is the best way that I can consume these when going from the various different projects into the central one? I have tried adding links but since we are using SQL to store the values and not the actual config it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3004210/1207195

Comment: The `ConfigurationManager` will always use the app.config from the application that is loaded into memory (unless you load a different one). Do you need to take values from multiple app.configs or do you just need to make sure you access the app.config from the program that is executing your DLL project?

Comment: That's what I tried to do but it didn't work for some reason. Is there any special configuration I need to do in order to get it to work that I skipped over?  I should be able to just access the app.config from the program executing the DLL. And if I need more I can feed the info in there.