# WCF Service Not Starting When Client Project Run

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

I am new to WCF in VS 2015 and have a simple query. I have a solution in which I have my basic WCF service and a simple Windows Forms client to test the service. It all compiles OK but if I set the client project as the startup project the WCF service is not started in IIS Express. If I set the WCF project as the startup project and then run the client form Explore it runs Ok and I can debug etc.

My question is how to start the WCF Service automatically  when I run the client project in Visual Studio

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Just Right-Click your solution, go to "Set StartUp Projects ..." and choose "Multiple startup projects" setting "Action" to "Run" for both your projects.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. One final query , in my client is there an easy way to switch between using the local hosted WCF and the one published to Azure without having to edit the app.confg file and change the endpoint address

Comment: You could use the debug and release parts of your App.config as described in [App.Config Transformation for projects which are not Web Projects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5109530/205233) as it is possible for Web.config.