# Cannot start WCF service from built UWP application

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, uwp

I have a solution that contains UWP project and WCF service project. I added references service WCF to UWP project and the service is hosted on IIS express OK if I run it from Visual Studio. But when I built it into the app and start it, the IIS express holding the WCF service cannot start even I call OpenAsync() in client side. Do we have some trick here?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42409851/wcf-service-not-starting-when-client-project-run?rq=1

Comment: No, man. I want to run it without Visual Studio.

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is no trick, it does not work that way. You need to *host* your WCF somewhere. VS does that in IIS Express for you while debugging, but you need to find another way to host it in production. And an UWP app seems to be the least likely way to succeed :(

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm trying to host that WCF service in console app. Does built UWP app contains the WCF code?

Comment: What "Does built UWP app contains the WCF code" mean?  How you host the WCF in console app? What the vs template you are using for WCF service currently?