# Where are the settings saved in a .NET 5 WinForms app?

Tags: winforms, .net-5

In a .NET Framework WinForms project, there was an App.config file in the project, which was an XML file that contained a configSection that would reference a class in System.Configuration, and a section for the userSettings themselves, like so:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561944e089">
        <section name="MyAppName.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561944e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<userSettings>
    <MyAppName.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Test" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Some Value</value>
        </setting>
    </MyAppName.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

And this created a file in the build folder with the app name plus .exe.config, as in MyAppName.exe.config.

But when I create a new WinForms project using .NET:

[image: New .NET WinForms Project]

There is no App.config in the solution.  I can edit the settings using the project properties:

[image: App Settings on Project Properties designer]

And I can access these values, and update them using the same Properties object and methods:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Test;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Test = textBox1.Text;

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

And everything seems to work, but when I examine the bin folder, there is no file that I can see for where the values are actually stored.

[image: Windows Explorer screen grab showing built application files]

Where is .NET 5 storing the saved application settings if not in a file in the same folder as the application's exe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**User settings** are stored in `user.config` file in the following path:

`%userprofile%\appdata\local\<Application name>\<Application uri hash>\<Application version>`

**Application settings** file are not created by default (unexpectedly), however if you create them manually beside the dll/exe file of your application, the configuration system respect to it. The file name should be `<Application name>.dll.config`. Pay attention to the file extension which is `.dll.config`.

You may want to take a look at the source code of the following classes:

- [LocalFileSettingsProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1d9e50cb4735df46d3de0cee5791e97295eaf588/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/LocalFileSettingsProvider.cs?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) (The default setting provider)
- [ClientSettingsStore](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1d9e50cb4735df46d3de0cee5791e97295eaf588/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/ClientSettingsStore.cs?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [ConfigurationManagerInternal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1d9e50cb4735df46d3de0cee5791e97295eaf588/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/Internal/ConfigurationManagerInternal.cs?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [ClientConfigurationPaths](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1d9e50cb4735df46d3de0cee5791e97295eaf588/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/ClientConfigPaths.cs?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

At the time of writing this answer [Application Settings for Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/application-settings-for-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) still doesn't have any entry for .NET 5 and redirects to 4.x documentations.

Comment: Do you know if it's still possible to do app.config transformations as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud? This does not seem to still be working for me.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I expect it to work. I *guess* lack of creating application config file by default is a VS/designer related issue not the config system issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a known (to .NET team) issue: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/7772.

Secondly the issue and the solution are pretty much described in your question:

> (before) ..there was an App.config file in the project,..
> (now) There is no App.config in the solution...

Add the missing app.config and everything will work just like it did before.