# DateTime compare (between) Date with day month year hours minutes and seconds

Tags: c#, performance, datetime, comparison

I would to check if a date fall between two limites.

StartDate = '2018-01-01 11:10:00'
EndDate = '2018-02-01 14:00:30'

1. CheckDate1 = '2018-01-01 11:09:00' -> FAIL
2. CheckDate2 = '2018-01-01 11:10:01' -> OK
3. CheckDate3 = '2018-01-01 14:00:31' -> FAIL
4. CheckDate4 = '2018-01-01 14:00:29' -> OK

I tried the following check:

```
CheckDateX >= StartDate && CheckDateX <= EndDate;
```

This doesn't seems to take the seconds into account.
So I tried the following check:

```
 CheckDateX.Ticks >= StartDate.Ticks  && CheckDateX.Ticks <= EndDate.Ticks;
```

But the result is also wrong.
Is there a correct and elegant way to compare to DateTime in C#?

Comment: You should share the actual code `StartDate = '2018-01-01 11:10:00' ` wont compile and is not a date

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp : I have not put the entire code.... you need to parse it first. It was more to add more details to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that link : [How to know if a DateTime is between a DateRange in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781611/how-to-know-if-a-datetime-is-between-a-daterange-in-c-sharp)
People provided answers and even an extension for the same issue you are facing.

Comment: In fact it was good without the ticks.....

Comment: I will flag my own question as duplicate :)

Comment: @pix check my answer for getting build time configuration from code. Somehow your question is removed because of duplicate but actually you can do it thru code. I dont have any other way to reach you. i will delete this comment after you read it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829276/how-to-obtain-build-configuration-at-runtime/56295835#56295835

Comment: Thx @JeevaSubburaj, my post as been deleted because the community requested it. This is really close to want I wanna do, but not enaught. I do not want to have to hard code anything. The best think would be to list all the preprocessor values inside a List variable. I really appreciate your concerne on this question :)